# infusionsoft campaign form css

Tags: wordpress, forms, builder, infusionsoft

so i need to style my form - i want the label to be inside of the field container as a place holder and i also want to stretch the input field containers but i am not winning:

```
 <style>

 .infusion-field-label-container {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.infusion-field-input-container {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.infusion-option label {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}

</style>


   <div align="center">
        <div class="infusion-field">
            <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name *</label>

            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label  for="inf_field_Phone1">Cell Number *</label>

            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Phone1" name="inf_field_Phone1" type="text"  />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label for="inf_field_Email">Email *</label>

            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


            <input type="submit" value="Register" />

        </div>


    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should first try it yourself, than post your try here. As it is now, you've just posted what you have without any notice what you already have tried. Stackoverflow help you with problems, not with writing entire code for you.

Comment: oh sorry i removed most of the css as it is not doing anything - at least not anything that i expect it to do. Should i just post it all as i had it even though nothing worked?

Comment: You always should post what is directly related to your problem and all what you already have tried, doesn't matter if it work or not. Than we all can help you in fixing it, depending on your specific information.

Comment: Thank you Brain - i updated the code above

Answer (score 0):

so i have most of it fixed:

```
<style>

 .infusion-field-label-container {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
.infusion-field-input-container {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.infusion-option label {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}

</style>


<style type="text/css">
.infusion-field-label-container {
text-align:Left;
}
.infusion-field-input-container {
width:300px;
}
.infusion-field-label-container {
vertical-align:Middle;
}

</style>   

   <div align="center">
        <div class="infusion-field">

            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name*"/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Phone1" name="inf_field_Phone1" type="text" placeholder="Cell Number*" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" placeholder="Email*" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


            <input type="submit" value="Register" />

        </div>


    </div>
</form>
```

Just cannot get the button styled - any hint please?